# Concatenate node to string containing a forward slash and dollar sign

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

This is my expected XML result:

```
        <category>
            <text>
                $course$/something
            </text>
        </category>
```

This is what I have tried:

```
        <xsl:variable name="course">$course$/</xsl:variable>
        <category>
            <text>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('$course', /office:document/office:meta/dc:title)" />
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('\$course\$/', /office:document/office:meta/dc:title)" />
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#36;course&#36;/', /office:document/office:meta/dc:title)" />                   
            </text>
        </category>
```

Using `<xsl:value-of select="concat('hello ', 'world')"/>` gives the expected result, but none of the above `value-of` work. All of them give an empty string (`<text />`).

I assumed that the node `/office:document/office:meta/dc:title` would be coerced into a string, but I am still confused about what is the proper way to escape the dollar sign and the forward slash.

Comment: Why does your variable have a forward slash, when your expected result has a backward slash?

Comment: My mistake, I mistyped it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you do simply:

```
<category>
    <text>
        <xsl:text>$course$/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="/office:document/office:meta/dc:title" />               
    </text>
</category>
```

---

Or, if you must:

```
<xsl:variable name="course">$course$/</xsl:variable>
<category>
    <text>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($course, /office:document/office:meta/dc:title)" />                
    </text>
</category>
</xsl:template>
```

Note the lack of quotes around the variable.

Comment: Great answer, that helped me to solve the problem partially. The other part of the problem was that I didn't declare the 'dc' namespace.